# CiviCRM profile search not working when integrated with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, profile, search, smartgroups

We're currently facing an issue. We are running Wordpress 4.9.8, and running CiviCRM. We're looking to publicly display a search widget on one of our wordpress pages, to search within a specific profile we have created. For background, this is how the process works:
Client fills out an application (Caldera Form), that form is processed and put in CiviCRM. We then go to each application and change each one to the contact type "Approved", which puts them into a Smart Group for only approved organizations. This approval system is so we can control which organizations are publicly displayed on the website. We then have made a profile with the specific contact information we want to display, and we have limited the profile listings to the specific "Approved" smart group.

Here's our issue: The search box appears publicly on our wordpress website, but any time someone attempts any search, the user is redirected to either a completely blank page (firefox) or a page with an HTTP 500 error (Chrome). The Url for this website follows this format, in case it's relevant: ....wordpress.org/..../?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile .

Here are some troubleshooting steps we've attempted and clarifying information to make help easier:

- The Profile has "Standalone Form Or Directory", "Search Views", and "Is the CiviCRM profile active" all selected
- The Profile's listings are limited to a specific Smart Group, in this case, the "Approved" Smart Group
- This Smart Group has "Expose Publically" selected
- Smart Group Visibility is set to "Public Pages"
- Smart Group has "is active" selected
- The Smart Group definitely has contacts in it, so it is not empty
- The Search does not work in any situation, whether or not we put in search parameters or not
- The error we get is "HTTP Error 500"

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Drake, and welcome to SE!  You don't mention this in your list but I assume you've checked the relevant permissions to make sure they're all set correctly for this type of search?  Also, what version of Civi are you using?  (That will be helpful for folks - you specified your WP version but not Civi.)

Comment: agree with Lesley that it could be a Permission issue

Answer (score 1):

Check your Permissions. There is a specific permission for seeing Listings.

> CiviCRM: profile listings
>   Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has privacy implications. Access public searchable directories.

Comment: I didn't read far enough to see the 500 error mention :-(

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error generally indicates a PHP error.  You can check your PHP error logs (which are probably the same as your web error logs unless you're doing something fancy) for more information.  If that solves your problem, great! Just come back here and mark this as the solution.  If this did NOT solve your problem, edit your original question to include the error you see that corresponds to the 500 error.